# Почему в фамилиях на -чёв/-щёв в ударном слоге пишется Ё, а не О?

Tags: орфография, фамилии

Уже давно интересует вопрос: почему в фамилиях типа Горбачёв, Фомичёв, Толмачёв, Хрущёв пишется Ё, а не О?
Если взять правила русского языка, то там чётко сказано, что

> [Буква О пишется] в суффиксе -ов- имен прилагательных: кумачовый,              камышовый, чесучовый; в том числе притяжательных прилагательных:  Кузьмичов (пиджак)

В соответствии с этим правилом такие фамилии должны были бы писаться Горбачов, Толмачов и т.д.
Кто-нибудь может объяснить, откуда есть пошло такое странное написание фамилий?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На имена собственные общие правила русского языка не распространяются. Да и фамилия далеко не притяжательное прилагательное, хотя и восходит к нему; на вопрос "чей?" фамилия давным-давно не отвечает. Об этом подробнее - ниже в цитате.

По сути же отступления от правила можно объяснить традицией. В стародавние времена там не только писалось, но и произносилось Е. Менять написание *фамилии* в угоду современным нормам правописания - это совсем не в духе языковых традиций.

Тут еще такой момент. В фамилиях часто подвижно ударение, даже в одной семье встречается вариации предпочтений типа Карташёв - К**а**ртышев. Использование различной орфографии окончательно запутало бы все юридические - и не только - вопросы.

Впрочем, и среди носителей фамилий встречаются разные ситуации и подходы, влекущие и разное написание. Известный пример - русский математик П. Л. Чебышёв. До недавнего времени встречалось написание Чебышов, особенно когда речь шла о т. н. полиномах Чебышёва (Ч**е**бышева, Чебышова), теория которых и была Чебышёвым разработана.

И вот что пишет "Вики" про фамилию Пафнутия Львовича и вообще о ситуации с выбором написания притяжательно суффикса в фамилиях.

> Фамилию учёного — по его собственному указанию — следует произносить
>   «Чебышо́в»[5]; в XIX веке такое произношение данной старинной
>   дворянской фамилии (писавшейся тогда — в условиях традиционного
>   неразличения е/ё на письме — как «Чебышевъ») было весьма
>   распространено[6] (предполагают, что эта фамилия по своему
>   происхождению является кратким притяжательным прилагательным,
>   образованным от антропонима Чебыш с ударением на окончании в косвенных
>   падежах и на последнем слоге основы в именительном падеже[7]).
>
> В XX веке в связи с тенденцией к обособлению фамилий на -ов/-ёв от
>   исходных притяжательных прилагательных[6] и всё ещё распространённым
>   неразличением на письме е/ё получило довольно широкое распространение
>   ошибочное произношение «Че́бышев» (с ударением на первом слоге) —
>   несмотря на чёткие рекомендации авторитетных источников[8][9]. 4-е
>   издание академического «Русского орфографического словаря» (2013)[10],
>   словарь ударений «Собственные имена в русском языке» (2001)[11] и
>   профильные академические издания[12][13], последовательно использующие
>   букву ё при передаче имён и названий, фиксируют в качестве
>   орфографической и орфоэпической нормы написание и произношение
>   Чебышёв.